# Accuracy and Confusion Matrix in Cross Validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am training a model to solve binary classification problem usign scikitlearn, and i wish to perform cross validation with 5 folds.

As metrics, i would like to get both the average accuracy and a confusion matrix over the 5 folds.

So, using `cross_validate` i can pass multiple metrics to the `scoring` parameter.

According to this [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#multimetric-scoring), i can `def` a function that returns the confusion matrix at each fold. In that piece of code, it uses `X` to predict some output through `.predict(X)`. But shouldn't a test set, `x_test`, have been used instead? And since, at each fold, a different test set is obtained from `cross_validate`, i don't understand how we can just pass `X` to both `confusion_matrix_scorer()` and `.predict()`. Other question, is `clf = svm` here, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#implementing-your-own-scoring-object) state that a callable scorer should satisfy

> It can be called with parameters (estimator, X, y), where estimator is the model that should be evaluated, X is validation data, and y is the ground truth target for X (in the supervised case) or None (in the unsupervised case).

When calling [cross_validate](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html), the cv folds are [first generated](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913b/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L267) and passed to independent fitting processes. Inside these processes, the test dataset is passed to a private `_score` method. From the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913b/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L703)

```
test_scores = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer, error_score)
```

which call the input scorrer with the defined parameters `(estimator, X, y)` [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913be6d7e485b792ea36e9268be31ed52d0/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L762)

```
scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
```

If you want to get both the average accuracy and a confusion matrix you can return these scores through a [dictionary](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#using-multiple-metric-evaluation)

**Example code**

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix

def confusion_matrix_scorer(clf, X, y):
      y_pred = clf.predict(X)
      cm = confusion_matrix(y, y_pred)
      acc = accuracy_score(y, y_pred)
      return {
          'acc': acc,
          'tn': cm[0, 0], 
          'fp': cm[0, 1],
          'fn': cm[1, 0], 
          'tp': cm[1, 1]
      }
```

Comment: Hello Miguel. I understand that part of returning a dictionary, but my question is about the variable `X` being used here. Isn't `X` the whole input data? And shouldn't you `.predict()` something just in a small part of `X` (the test set, lets call `X_test`)? How can you pass `X_test` to `confusion_matrix_scorer` if you get that variable from `cross_validate`?

Comment: the input `X` is your test data becuause you evaluate your model performance on your test data. So you pass `X_test` and `y_test` to the custom scorer function and return some metric values, cross_validate just return the evaluation metrics for each fold.

Comment: cross_validate just generate indices for the train and test samples, inside `_fit_and_score` the split is made. [Reference](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913b/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L674)